# Firefox Quantum 66 ignoring CSS styling in dropdown menu

Tags: linux, linux-mint, firefox

I have noticed in my Firefox browser running on Linux Mint 18.2 that Firefox will ignore CSS stylings for dropdown menus, and instead defaults to what looks like system themes. This issue is not present when I run Google Chrome or Firefox on a Windows 10 machine, so this seems to be an issue strictly with Linux.

I have already tried setting `display.use_system_colors` to false and setting `widget.content.gtk-theme-override` to `Adwaita:light` in the `about:config` page but this has not helped.

An example code can be seen in http://jsfiddle.net/W5B5p

For me, this will display as:
[image: dropdown css not being applied]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can configure my Linux/Firefox settings so it renders the CSS stylings?

Comment: A comment from [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283086#c42) that may be useful: _"widget.content.gtk-theme-override" with "adwaita:light" stopped working, use "Adwaita" instead._

Comment: No luck with that either unfortunately